# Is it possible using Cerberus to enable ADB Debugging on my broken android

Tags: adb, wireless-debugging

I have a OnePlus Nord 5G and stupidly I never enabled `ADB Debugging`, and now the screen is completely ruined. However, I still have the Cerberus connectivity. I have tried through the various means `Start Service` and `Start Application` to try and enable ADB debugging. Is this at all possible or am I chasing a dead end?

I have also downloaded Screen Stream through Google Play to my phone and then started it remotely through Cerberus with hopes of trying to connect. However, I am met with a `Press Start to begin` on the Screen Stream webpage `192.168.1.106:8080`. Any way around this as I cannot touch the screen to begin anything.

Comment: I don't think there are a lot users around that are familiar with Cerberus. May be you should describe what functions you can execute using Cerberus at the moment.

Comment: Is this the [Cerberus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerberus_(Android)) trojan horse?